# How to deploy a Dockerized ML Based app to our own servers (not on the cloud)?

Tags: python, docker

How to deploy a Dockerized ML Based app to our own servers (not on the cloud)?  And how to make it available on the internet for a small user group of say 200 only? Do I need multiple docker instances (and Kubernetes) for this kind of small user group? If I use only one docker instance, how the simultaneous requests from say 2 or more parallel users will be handled?...Appreciate your answer and thanks in advance!